# AR quick look Web vertical (wall) tracking

Tags: augmented-reality, usdz, arquicklook

Is any posible solutions to make usdz files be tracked on walls in AR quick look?

Looks that model-viwer doesn't support ios vertical tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use model viewer library, for place in wall augmented reality.
https://modelviewer.dev/examples/augmentedreality/#wall

Its necessary add the word wall in  ar-placement

```
<model-viewer
      src="https://cdn.glitch.global/532ed894-14f5-4266-aae1-e40c044a59ea/respisa.glb?v=1675375629266"
      ios-src="https://cdn.glitch.global/532ed894-14f5-4266-aae1-e40c044a59ea/respisa.usdz?v=1675375748399"            
      ar ar-placement="wall" 
      camera-controls touch-action="pan-y"
      ar-modes="webxr scene-viewer quick-look"
      poster="https://cdn.glitch.global/532ed894-14f5-4266-aae1-e40c044a59ea/poster%20(1).webp?v=1675375614612"
      shadow-intensity="1"
      autoplay
      id="color">
      
      <div class="progress-bar hide" slot="progress-bar">
        <div class="update-bar"></div>
      </div>
      <button slot="ar-button" id="ar-button">Ver en RA</button>
      <div id="ar-prompt">
        <img src="https://cdn.glitch.global/e0ded90b-d904-4d66-8a8b-70c809a73bc0/ar_hand_prompt.png?v=1675185744771" />
      </div>
      
         <div class="controls" ,="" id="color-controls">
    <button data-color="#ff0000">Red</button>
    <button data-color="#00ff00">Green</button>
    <button data-color="#0000ff">Blue</button>
  </div>
      
      
      
    </model-viewer>
```

You can use the mglb for android and you can use usdz for iOS (https://modelviewer.dev/docs/#entrydocs-augmentedreality-attributes-iosSrc)

You can use my proyect https://glitch.com/edit/#!/remix/https://glitch.com/edit/#!/repisa

Or can try it  https://repisa.glitch.me